# Camera Roll, User denied access, -3311 React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, camera-roll

This is how my code looks like

```
componentDidMount() {
  var fetchParams = {
    first: 25
  };

  CameraRoll.getPhotos(fetchParams, this.storeImages.bind(this), this.logError);
}

storeImages (data) {
  var assets = data.edges;
  var images = assets.map((asset) => asset.node.image);
  this.setState({
    images: images
  });
}

logError (error) {
  console.warn(error);
}
```

Once I reached this point in the app, I got the following error:

```
Object {code: -3311, message: "User denied access", nativeStackIOS: Array[9], domain: "ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain"}
```

Any clue about how to fix it?

By the way, the pop-up window that asks for permission is never triggered.

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling `CameraRoll.getPhotos` iOS fires up a permissions dialog.

[image: iOS Permissions dialog]

If you don't allow access to the photos, you'll get the error you are reporting. If you allow access everything should be fine. You won't be able to access a users photos without their permission.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the pop-up alert you are mention is not triggered at all. If I ask for the user's location, I can see the pop-up alert but not for the camera roll. Is there a way to force the alert to pop-up? @dbanck

Comment: same problem not getting permission dialog ,and getting the error is code:-3311 "ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain",User denied access

Answer (score 0):

You can use this repo (https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions) to check permissions and request them anytime / anywhere you want in the app :-) 
I'm using it and it works well 
Hope it helps 
Example:

#### Install

```
npm install --save react-native-permissions
rnpm link
const Permissions = require('react-native-permissions');
```

#### Check Request

```
Permissions.getPermissionStatus('photo').then(response => {
    //response is one of: 'authorized', 'denied', 'restricted', or 'undetermined'
});
```

#### Request Permissions

```
Permissions.requestPermission('photo').then(response => {

});
```

Comment: The API changed. It is not "check" and "request".